# Delete all indices in Lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net

I want to delete **all** the previously created indices. I am using `Lucene.net`.

I tried the following:

```
Term term = new Term(); //empty because I want to delete all the indices
IndexReader rdr = IndexReader.Open(_directory);

rdr.DeleteDocuments(term);
rdr.Close();
```

But I get error. Any idea how to go about it?

Answer (score 19):

The best way to delete an index is to wipe the filesystem directory. However, if you wan't to regenerate the index, the easiest way is to open a new indexwriter with the create parameter as true. It will start a new index deleting the contents of the existing one.

Answer (score 9):

although the thread is old i think it's better to give answer.. might be useful for somebody else.
deleteAll() method of IndexWriter can be used to delete all documents indexed.

Answer (score 1):

As Jokin said, the easiest was is to delete all of the files within the directory. i.e.;

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"IndexLocation");
Parallel.ForEach(directoryInfo.GetFiles(), file => {
            file.Delete();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Lucene.Net API Doc](http://lucene.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.4.0/):

> `public static IndexReader Open(Directory);`
>
> Expert: Returns a read/write IndexReader reading the index in the given Directory, with a custom IndexDeletionPolicy. NOTE: Starting in 3.0 this will return a **readOnly** IndexReader. Throws CorruptIndexException if the index is corrupt. Throws IOException if there is a low-level IO error.

i guess you should try

```
IndexReader rdr = IndexReader.Open(_directory, true);
```