# Lucene.NET - getting corrupt indices on server shutdowns

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

So I'm very happy with the Lucene.NET implementation on a current site other than the odd occasional index corruption.  I won't get any errors but I'll start noticing results coming back double, triple, etc.  If I use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) I'll see oddness with the index, lots of documents showing up multiple times.  So I'm thinking that maybe the finalizer / Dispose isn't being called and thus this corrupts the indices?

Anyone have any experience preventing this from happening?  I know that if I manually delete the index files from disk that everything returns to normal.  Should I be trying to do that on each service restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to use the [indexwriter constructor overload](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#IndexWriter%28org.apache.lucene.store.Directory,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer,%20boolean,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexDeletionPolicy,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength%29) that allows one to specify that the indices should be recreated.  This deletes the old index files.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196509/delete-all-indices-in-lucene-net) helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, this doesn't sound like index corruption, but it does sound like you might be entering duplicate documents into your index.

How are documents being placed in your index?  Is there a field that's being used as a primary key?  How are you checking against this key when adding documents?  Do you add all your documents in one pass and never update them?  Or do you check for updates and update later.

Perhaps most interesting from a testing point of view, do you end up with an apparently consistent set of duplicates once the service has been shut down?  That really wouldn't point to an index corruption, would it?

Good luck,

Comment: No, I can verify that the search index is good for a while.  I perform searches and get back only one result per match.  But thanks for the helpful try.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, if OS gone with blusescreen, the lucene index may corrupt.
I guess, maybe some lucene index update is writing to disk in OS level's, and OS gone blusescreen, then make the index corrupted.