# Lucene.Net - how to delete .csf files?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net version 2.9.4.1.
Here's my search service:

```
public class FooSearchServiceLucene : IFooSearchService
{
    private readonly Directory dir;
    private readonly IndexWriter indexWriter;
    private readonly IPersonRepository personRepository;

    public PersonSearchServiceLucene(string luceneIndexDir, IFooRepository fooRepository)
    {
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository;

        dir = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(luceneIndexDir));
        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29),
                                        IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    }
    ...
    public void RebuildSearchIndex()
    {
        // delete all documents
        indexWriter.DeleteAll();
        indexWriter.Commit();

        // create a new index
        var items = fooRepository.GetAll();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            AddDocument(person);
        }

        indexWriter.Commit();
    }
}
```

This `FooSearchServiceLucene` is a singleton, because I can have only one `IndexWriter` at a time, and I'm using `Near real time search` functionality.
When I call `RebuildSearchIndex` method, all `.del` files will be deleted, old search segments will still exist on the file system, and new search segment will be created?

My disk space is growing rapidly. How can I delete old `.cfs` files without restarting `IIS`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should add `IIS` to the title and tags as well..

Comment: But I want to handle this without interacting with IIS/Application pool

Comment: Yes, but nevertheless it is related to IIS

Comment: Nope, it's related to `Lucene.Net` and `Commit` method.

Comment: Okay, then sorry :) Btw, I think this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/229800/568266

Comment: `FooSearchServiceLucene` is singleton and `indexWriter` is `readonly`. Once opened and closed, it cannot be reopened or re-instantiated :(

Comment: How I read that post, it will delete all related files to the IndexWriter. I know everyone wants their fields to be `readonly` if set in the constructor (so do I:)). However, in this situation, it might be the easiest way, to drop the `readonly` and go for a new `IndexWriter`.

Comment: Eventually I'll have to do that unless I make this `Commit` to work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all your documents in a single segment, you will have to call IndexWriter.Optimize(). Note that this call can take a while and will consume lots of ressources, so you should only call it at moments when the traffic on your website is low.

Also, if you have an IndexSeacher opened on your index files when you call Optimize/Commit, Lucene will not be able to remove these files. You have to close the Searcher before you Optimize/Commit in your RebuildSearchIndex method.

Comment: `IndexWriter.Optimize()` will create .cfs and .cfx files. Old segments (.cfs) will remain on file system until I close `indexWriter`.

Comment: if you used the default merge policy an Optimize will merge all segments into a single one, if after that you still have other compound files in the Index Directory it means that these files are still in use somewhere and lucene cannot remove them. Make sure that you close every IndexReaders referencing the files.

Comment: I closed all searchers and readers... Can I somehow debug `Commit` method to see why .cfs files are not deleted (who's holding the reference, etc)?

Comment: i dont know about debugging it in from the commit method, but the ProcessExplorer utility from sysinternal (free) can help you with that. It can show you the file handles your IIS process has.